# Reloading renderer3d with new data

Tags: javascript, vtk, xtk

I am trying to use XTK to display VTK files that are dynamically generated as a result of some scientific calculation.

For this, I am attempting to call the following JavaScript function with a new `result_file` every time I submit a form (using jQuery's .submit() event handler).

```
function renderResult(result_file) {
  var r = new X.renderer3D();
  r.container = 'visualization';
  r.init();
  r.camera.position = [0, 0, 2.5];
  r.camera.focus = [0, 0, 0];
  var solution = new X.mesh();
  solution.file = result_file;
  r.add(solution);
  r.render();
}
```

Unfortunately, while the XTK progress bar indicates that a new render is triggered, the visualization stays fixed to the original rendering. Is there some way to reset or reload a `renderer3d` with new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the old X.mesh, update the file property and then call a mesh.modified() event.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. My knowledge of JavaScript scoping is quite poor, so I am not exactly sure how much to initialize (renderer3d, mesh, ...) on page load, and how to access these properties later on to change them. But I will try to figure this out. Thanks again.